# Timer C# Stop() doesn't really stop

Tags: c#, timer

I have a form which includes a textbox showing the time passing with an interval of 1 second up till 2 minutes. It is working ok. However I need the timer to stop when a round of game is over and start again when a button from another form is clicked. So I have `_timer.Stop()` in the timer_tick event handler and `_timer.Start()` in the button `click` event handler of Form 2.

My problem is that the timer then starts from how much time passes until I press the button on the other form and not from 0:00 again. Any Ideas?

This is the code regarding the timer:

```
 private DateTime _myDateTime;
 private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
 private DateTime newDate;

 public Tournament()
 {
     _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     _timer.Interval = 1000;
     _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
     _myDateTime = DateTime.Now;

     newDate = new DateTime();
     newDate = newDate.AddMinutes(2.00);
     _timer.Start();
     InitializeComponent();
 }

 void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_myDateTime);
        this.textBox1.Text = diff.ToString(@"mm\:ss");

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(diff.ToString());

        if (newDate.Minute == dt.Minute)
        {
           _timer.Stop();
           _myDateTime = DateTime.Now;

           displayPointsOrResults();

           this.textBox1.Text = diff.ToString(@"mm\:ss");  
        }
  }
```

In `displayPointsOrResults()` I am creating instance of another form `Points()` so in Points form I have button 1 and I have this in its event handler apart other things which does not concern the timer:       `tournament.Timer1.Start();`

Where I am getting the timer from the tournament class and starting it again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try _timer.Stop(); _timer.Enabled = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah the global vars, blessing and curse together.
Do you have resetted the `_myDateTime` to DateTime.Now,  when you press the button?

Comment: I don't wish to argue with the downvoter, but the problem lies exactly in the mishandling of global vars, and, while my answer is not as well documented like the one from Mr Skeet, it is certainly not wrong. Ah well, let's go on...

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that the timer then starts from how much time passes until I press the button on the other form and not from 0:00 again.

Well yes, it would - you're resetting `_myDateTime` when you *stop* the timer:

```
_timer.Stop();
_myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

You should move that second line to the point where you restart it.

Note that your title is incorrect - the timer really *is* stopping, in that it's not ticking any more. The timer isn't actually performing the timing, if you see what I mean - it's *just* a way of invoking an event handler regularly. The problem is within the event handler itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the timer and restart it, should set the datetime to now.

```
_myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```